# list files inside of windows folder on cmd

Tags: java, file, cmd, io, console

I am trying to understand I/O in java. This is the code I have.

What I need to do is:

1) Should I write `java list "C:\windows"` on cmd and I need to see all the files inside of Windows.

2) I didn't understand `File dir = new File(args[0]);` What does this `args[0]` why we use it?

```
    public class App {
    public static void main(String []args)
{
    try {

        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Wrong usage");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        File dir = new File(args[0]);

        if (!dir.isDirectory()) {
            System.err.println("seems there is no directory ");
            System.exit(-1);                
        }



        File [] files = dir.listFiles(); 


        System.setProperty("user.home", args[0]);

        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory())
                System.out.printf("%s<DIR>%n", file.getName());
            else
                System.out.printf("%s%n", file.getName());

        }           

    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }   

}
}
```

Comment: args[0] refers to the first argument you provided in the main method. On that note, are you only seeking to find files or directories as well?

Comment: all files and directories. the code is working but ı coldnt make it work with cdm. what ı should  write on cmd ?

Comment: what do you mean you cannot make it work with cmd? are you not sure how to run your application?

Comment: my teacher wrote this code . its not mine.  ı just dont know how to run this code on cmd.

Comment: what should ı write on cmd ? ı konow this is a realy stupid question but forgive me ı am new about java

Comment: select answer if you are now good to go. dont just leave the community without saying a thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you need is already in your question. After you compile the `App.java` will have a result call `App.class`, this is your class. To run it from the command you can use the `java` command line tool. It something like

```
java App C:/Windows
```

Where `App` is your application class without the `.class`. The `C:/Windows` is the parameter for your program, which is captured by the `args[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to compile the java class

```
javac -g App.java
```

Then you can run it using:

```
java App "c:\\windows"
```